# How to find what file is deleted in macOS?

Tags: macos

I have a question regarding macOS file operation.
Is there a log file showing which file has been deleted on Mac recently?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/325653).  What is the actual issue you're trying to resolve?

Comment: The linked dupe is about files being accessed, but it’s essentially the same question/answer.  You can log those activities, but you can’t do so retroactively.